# Custom Actionbar layout not showing

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-linearlayout

Hey guys I'm trying to implement a search view but my actionbar does not display the things I want. It's just empty.
Here is my activity code

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
    setContentView(R.layout.search_tag);
    android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.searchview);
    actionBar.setDisplayOptions(android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM | android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME);

}
```

My activity extends AppCompatActivity, just mentioning that to avoid confusion. Here is my searchview:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:theme="@style/Theme.MyTheme">

    <EditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/searchfield"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:imeOptions="actionGo"
        android:inputType="textWebEmailAddress"
        android:text="www.google.com" />


</LinearLayout>
```

The main layout for the activity is just an empty linear layout. I think I'm missing something. Anyone has an idea what is wrong with the code?

Thanks in advance

Comment: add `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);` before `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`

Answer (score 0):

You calling `setContentView` and then working on the view later. Try moving the actionbar code before the `setContentView` method is called.